# express js blank root page

Tags: express, vue.js

I have simple vue js app with next express js config file

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
app.use(express.static('.'));
server.listen(1111);
```

Result of build is located in **/dist** folder. However my express js file is located in **/**

After I run it I see blank page on **localhost:1111** and actually it retrieves index.html from **/**  but, I see my app on **localhost:1111/dist** and it retrieves index.html from **/dist**

My purpose is to receive index.html from **/dist** when I visit **localhost:1111**.

I've tried to change express config to **app.use(express.static('./dist'))** and similar to this. But it only breaks anything (i'm not able to reach my app on **localhost:1111/dist** and **localhost:1111/**)

In general I have next project structure

**/** -> express js config is here and basic index.html is here

**/dist** -> build result is located here (index.html + static files)

**/dist/static** -> static files are here

**/build** -> webpack config is here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem why `app.use(express.static('dist'));` didn't work was that in index.html I had link to other files like `/dist/static/..` what is not correct if my root folder is **dist**. So, despite moderator set that webpack doesn't related to this the solution was to change webpack config for production to make **build** script generate links to file in **/dist/index.html** like **/static/..** instead of **/dist/static/..**

And obviously I had to change

```
app.use(express.static('.'));
```

to

```
app.use(express.static('dist'));
```

As a conclusion - it make sense to check generated index.html and analyze if the paths there are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this issue may come because of, the app doesn't server from the root folder.
For example, */home/user/path-to-the-project"* The app need to serve like this.

So here you need to change like below,

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));`

For more information, you check express doc. [See here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)